# Meteor reading CSV files to populate database don't work after deploy

Tags: meteor

So I have a bunch of data that I want to load into database from CSV. I've hacked together a solution that works in local development, but when I deploy to meteor.com, it no longer works.

I'm loading the csv file in the folder /server/data/:

```
function readData(name){
    var fs = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('fs');   
    var path = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('path');   
    var base = path.resolve('.');
    var data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(base, '/server/data/', name));
    return CSVToArray(data);
}
```

After I deploy to meteor.com, i got:

```
INFO Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/meteor/containers/98eb1286-120b-ee84-8e98-ce673fa2eab7/public/data/categories.csv'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:240:18)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:128:15)
    at readData (app/server/models.js:10:16)
    at app/server/categories.js:6:7
    at /meteor/containers/98eb1286-120b-ee84-8e98-ce673fa2eab7/bundle/server/server.js:132:63
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/meteor/containers/98eb1286-120b-ee84-8e98-ce673fa2eab7/bundle/server/underscore.js:76:11)
    at /meteor/containers/98eb1286-120b-ee84-8e98-ce673fa2eab7/bundle/server/server.js:132:7
```

Any idea how I can get meteor to see the csv file after deployment?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is old, but it still ranks high on certain keyword searches. So, if you're using **Meteor 0.6.5+**, you can use the new [Assets API](http://docs.meteor.com/#assets).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that meteor only bundles files that it knows about (ie. JS/CSS/HTML/+more depending on which packages you use) up when it deploys.

Try putting the file you need in the `public` directory (this directory is exempt from the above rule).

Comment: I tried putting data in public but no dice. Just tried again and same result.

Comment: Can you access the file directly from the web-browser?

Comment: Is there a good way to get a file with a different extension into the bundle without putting it in public? I've got an auth related file that I've been forced to repackage into a JS as a hack for now.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to SamuelDavis and Tom Coleman's tips. I ended up figuring out what the problem is. Turns out the bundled app is no longer formated as client, public, and server. I ended up debugging it by running meteor bundle to create a tarball. extract the tarball and took a look inside to find where the data folder is. Tom was also right that the data folder needed to be in the public folder in order to get bundled in.

Comment: Glad you figured out your problem :)

Comment: How do you access the file in the public folder from the `/server` directory?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the base directory is not in the same location that contains the file '/server/data/xxx.csv'.

Before you try anything else, log the base path after calling "var base = path.resolve('.'). If that value is what you expected, log the files that appear in that directory. Again if the files are what you expected, navigate into the /server folder and print out those directories and so forth.

This should pinpoint you to which folder and/or directory is missing and should indicate where you should place the CSV file in future.

Comment: I used fs.readdir() to read files in the directory but they don't seem to get logged in the meteor log. I tried both console.log() and Meteor._debug(). Both commands works in local development server and I get a print out of all the files in base directory'

Comment: Oh wait actualy turns out I need to used fs.readdirSync(). I'm debugging the path now. turns out the bundled app on the server has completely different directory format.